# Unity OnMatchList inaccesible due to its protection level

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, multiplayer

I have seen that there are more answers to similar questions, but none of these helped me. I hope you can.

I have a Unity2D shooter game and I try to make a menu for UNET. I watched a youtube tutorial from Brackeys to make the menu (https://youtu.be/V4oRs26vAw8?list=PLPV2KyIb3jR5PhGqsO7G4PsbEC_Al-kPZ&t=896) and when he runs the project it shows me the error: "error CS0122: 'UnityEngine.Networking.Match.ListMatchResponse' is inaccessible due to its protection level. I found out that this might happen when you access for example a private variable from another function, but I access a function from Unity and I can not modify its type (I believe). Any ideas? Thank you.

```
public void OnMatchList(bool success, string extendedInfo, ListMatchResponse matchList)
{
    status.text = "";
    if (matchList == null)
    {
        status.text = "Couldn't get room list.";
        return;
    }

    ClearRoomList();
    foreach(MatchDesc match in matchList.matches)
    {
        GameObject _roomListItemGO = Instantiate(roomListItemPrefab);
        _roomListItemGO.transform.SetParent(roomListParent);
        // Have a component sit on the gameobject
        // that will take care of setting up the name / amount of users.
        // as well as setting up a callback function that will join the game.

        roomList.Add(_roomListItemGO);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your Unity Version? The example seems to use a depricated API ...

Comment: @derHugo Unity 2018.3.11f1, I upgrade it now to see if something changes

Comment: @derHugo Still not working.. same issue

Comment: As said I think it is deprecated .. the only mentioning of `ListMatchResponse` I found in 5.6

Comment: Do you know how should I change it or with what? @derHugo    I have not worked with a UNET Menu before.

Answer (score 0):

'MatchDesc' has been renamed to 'MatchInfoSnapshot'.
Just replace it and it should work fine.